# C++ stream as function parameter. Can I do something like function(a << "hi" << b);

Tags: c++

In my code I have a lot of things like

```
message << a << "hi" << b;  
show_error(message.str())
```

Is there a way to make it a one liner like `function(a << "hi" << b);`

Comment: What is the type of `message`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answers here are provocative but they don't give me the look I wanted. I ended up doing a function macro, for example:

```
#define SHOW_ERROR(e)   { stringstream ss; ss << e; show_error(ss.str()); }
void show_error(string message)
{
//show error here
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a little trick using variadic templates. It allows you to write code like:

```
show_error(format(5, "-hi-", 3.4));
show_error(format("wow: ", std::string("test"), 25, 2.1));
```

The `format` function looks like this:

```
template<class... T>
std::string format(T... args)
{
    std::stringstream ss;

    int dummy[sizeof...(T)] = { (ss << args, 0)... };

    return ss.str();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do it in one line, like this:

```
show_error(((stringstream&)(message << a << " hi " << b)).str());
```

Operator `<<` returns the stream on which it is called, so this should be possible. Here is a [demo on ideone](http://ideone.com/gesz5w).

You could improve on this approach by changing `show_error` to take an `ostream`, casting it to `stringstream&`, and getting a string out of it:

```
show_error(const string& s); // Your original function
show_error(ostream& oss) {   // Your new overload
    show_error(((stringstream&)oss).str());
}
```

Now you can write this:

```
show_error(message << a << "hi" << b);
```

Answer (score 0):

Yep, a class like this ought to do it:

```
class mystringstream {
    std::stringstream _stream;
  public:
    template<class T>
    mystringstream &operator <<(const T &v) { _stream << v; return *this; }
    operator std::string() const { return _stream.str(); }
};

function(mystringstream() << a << "hi" << b);
```